# android RecyclerView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and inside I have a RecyclerView. and child RecyclerView is no scrolling I try put a child RecyclerView inside a scrollView NeastedCrollView but it doesn't work :

No I have this parent recyclerView:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/text_dp_20"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

and this is a child list :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: you can add a gesture listener. Watch for swipes and control the recycle view yourself. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: Are you looking for this?
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ArdBfyigwTM/VnvvWr_kSBI/AAAAAAAAINs/cLsJkMiJOYA/s1600/Screenshot_2015-12-24-17-51-29.png

Comment: @JavadDehban no all is VERTICAL

Comment: are you looking for this??? https://github.com/javaddehban/javaddehban/blob/master/photo_2020-09-22_13-07-51.jpg

Comment: @JavadDehban yes I try do this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `NestedScrollView`, `RecyclerView` handles everything about scrolling!
use the below links guidelines for improving and optimizing your RecyclerViews, here some useful references:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/
https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

follow one of them step by step!

Comment: can you share your project, or create a module and share it on GitHub?

Comment: I try , I want to have a two recycling view which are scroll vertical and a secend is no wrap content  , it have 150 dp

Answer (score 0):

you're first need in one recylerView in main activity

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

2-and in MainActivity.java :

```
   LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(buildItemList());
    rvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

3- recyclerView in Layout Adapter:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_sub_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

4- in Adapter :

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
            itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.getContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false
    );
    layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(item.getSubItemList().size());

    // Create sub item view adapter
    SubItemAdapter subItemAdapter = new SubItemAdapter(item.getSubItemList());

    itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setAdapter(subItemAdapter);
    itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
```

the end.

you see full code in [link](https://github.com/alghifari/RecycledViewPoolExample)